# Data Dinamica Azure Data Factory

Tags: data, microsoft-azure

boa tarde!

Estou fazendo um projeto no qual subo dados do SAP para o meu SQL, via Azure Data Factory. Acontece que preciso ter uma partition column dinamica, por data:

Preciso, por ex, pegar esta data dinamicamente: 20200901

E também existem na ferramenta pré-funções já existentes, por ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão é que preciso formatar essa data, para ao invés de vir "2020-09-01T00:00:00.0000000Z", vir assim "20200901"

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Obrigada!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido

@{formatDateTime(getPastTime(1,'Day'),'yyyyMMdd')}